# kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Tags: android, fragment, kotlin

I'm new to `Android` here. What can be the situation for my problem? I'm trying to present my fragment to the `MainActivity`. Any suggestions will help. Thanks

Main Activity Class...

```
class NavigationActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_schedule)

        val toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar) as Toolbar
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar) // setup toolbar
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_map)

        val drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout) as DrawerLayout
        val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close)
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle) // navigation drawer
        toggle.syncState()

        val navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view) as NavigationView
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this) //setup navigation view

}
```

My Fragment Class..

```
 class fragment_schedule : Fragment() {
 override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
   // Inflate the layout for this fragment
   return inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_schedule, container, false)
}
```

Comment: Probably wrong layout file is used. Check out this line: `setContentView(R.layout.fragment_schedule)`

Answer (score 1):

Also another reason could be that you had put setContentView below the item that caused this exception. At least it is how I fixed it on my side.

Answer (score 1):

Sanislondra figured out that the reason why I was getting this exception because the `navigation graphs id` in the xml should match the `id` of the `menu items` in the bottom navigation menu xml.

Answer (score 0):

Your layout apparently has no toolbar component with id `R.id.toolbar`, that's why `findViewById(...)` returns `null` that can't be cast to `Toolbar`.

Null-safety is important built in part of `Kotlin`. It helps you to reveal most of NPEs on the early stages of development. Read [more about null safety](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html) on official `Kotlin` site.

#### If presence of toolbar component is essential, then never make `val toolbar` variable nullable.

In this case your current code is correct, don't change it. Instead correct your layout/wrong toolbar id problem.

`var toolbar: Toolbar? = null` defines nullable variable of type `Toolbar` and no exception will be risen if there will be no toolbar component in your activity layout, *but if you expect to really have this component, you will get other exceptions later or even unpredictable behaviour of your program that will surprise you or app users*.

#### On the other hand you should make null-safety checks while using nullable variables

In that case your code should be slightly changed. Important part:

```
val toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar) as Toolbar?
```

`?` means that if `findViewById` returns `null`, then this `null` would be assigned to `val toolbar` instead of rising `kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` exception

Full code block example:

```
 val toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar) as Toolbar? // toolbar now is nullable 

 if(toolbar != null) {
 // kotlin smart cast of toolbar as not nullable value
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar) // setup toolbar
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_map)

        val drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout) as DrawerLayout
        val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close)
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle) // navigation drawer
        toggle.syncState()
}
```